# Android Studio + Andy: the Emulator does not run

Tags: android-studio, emulation

My situation is: I ran the Studio's debugger and selected Andy in the window "Device Chooser". But in the debugger's window I got the message:

> Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application
>   using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse

The real device is disabled. Andy shows me that started the application, but in a modal window has a message:

> Application X is waiting for the debugger to attach

Please help me to understand. Thank you!